# Missing arguments in a nested function

Tags: function, nested

I follow a python course on finance about portfolio theory. I have to create a function with a nested function in it.

My problem is I have a error message of "neg_sharpe_ratio() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'er' and 'cov'" whereas to my mind 'er' and 'cov' are already defined in my function msr below. So I understand how they are missing.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def msr(riskfree_rate, er, cov):
    
    n= er.shape[0]
    init_guess= np.repeat(1/n, n)
    bounds=((0.00, 1.0),)*n
    weights_sum_to_1 = {
        'type' :'eq' , #
        'fun' : lambda weights: np.sum(weights) - 1 ## 
    } 
    def neg_sharpe_ratio(weights,riskfree_rate, er, cov):
        r = erk.portfolio_return(weights, er)
        vol = erk.portfolio_vol(weights,cov)
        return -(r-riskfree_rate)/vol

    results = minimize( neg_sharpe_ratio, init_guess, 
                args=(cov,), method="SLSQP", 
                options={'disp': False},
                constraints=( weights_sum_to_1),
                bounds=bounds
                      )
    return results.x
```

TypeError: neg_sharpe_ratio() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'er' and 'cov'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be interested, I find my mistake..
Indeed, I forgot to define correctly the arguments of my function neg_share_ratio in my function minimize.

Here is the code amended:

from scipy.optimize import minimize
def msr(riskfree_rate, er, cov):

```
n= er.shape[0]
init_guess= np.repeat(1/n, n)
bounds=((0.00, 1.0),)*n
weights_sum_to_1 = {
    'type' :'eq' , #
    'fun' : lambda weights: np.sum(weights) - 1 ## 
} 
def neg_sharpe_ratio(weights,riskfree_rate, er, cov):
    r = erk.portfolio_return(weights, er)
    vol = erk.portfolio_vol(weights,cov)
    return -(r-riskfree_rate)/vol

results = minimize( neg_sharpe_ratio, init_guess, 
            args=(weights,riskfree_rate,er,cov), method="SLSQP", 
            options={'disp': False},
            constraints=( weights_sum_to_1),
            bounds=bounds
                  )
return results.x code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `neg_sharpe_ratio` is able to reference any of the variables passed in and made by the function `msr` without needing those same variables passed into it itself. Therefore you should be able to remove the paramters `riskfree_rate`, `er`, and `cov` from the `neq_sharpe_ratio` function definition and have it work, as those variables are passed into its parent function, leaving you with:
`def neg_sharpe_ratio(weights):`

Comment: I edited my question by deleting assignment of er and cov (it was an unsuccessful test)

Comment: @Roms Did removing the 3 unnecessary parameters not work?

Comment: I tried, and I had: "neg_sharpe_ratio() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given", which is also really weird

Comment: @Roms That would be because the callback function that `minimize` expects has a second optional parameter for arguments. Trying adding a second parameter and printing its results to see what is passed. I haven't used the scipy library myself so this part I'm not too familiar with